# Ubuntu freezes on boot or won't boot

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, freeze

I have boought 4 asus mini Pcs and installed ubuntu 18.04 and some required packages and libraries I needed. My problem is, One of them freezes on boot, it was ok at first but after some restarting, it became faulty, I thought maybe the problem arises from hardware, but I installed windows 10 on it and it booted successfully.
How can I find the problem. If it's a hardware issue, how can I make sure?
The mini pc is ASUS pn40 with 120gb ssd and 4gb ram.

Comment: I would suggest running memtest86 on it; ie. memory test.  Windows & GNU/Linux allocate memory differently (*top/bottom end..*), so if it's bad memory; one can experience the flaw more often than the other depending on where the flaw is.  This is only a thought.

Comment: I tried changing the ram but it still had problem. I suspected the flash drive and changed the drive and tried installing Ubuntu 19, it was running ok. Now the problem is that it won't boot without monitor attached